# Can I refresh a Yii CGridView from js?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

When a "Create" modal dialog is submitted via XHR
Then the rows in a Yii CGridView should be refreshed.

I've tried to achieve this by rendering the new gridview in the XHR "create" action and then inserting it into the page via `$("#list").html(response)`, but rendering a `CGridView` causes jQuery `<script>` include tags to be registered for inclusion, and so when I introduce those tags into the page they reload jQuery, which wipes out my [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handlers, so a bunch of stuff breaks.

Which has me thinking, "the GridView knows how to refresh itself. heck, it does all the time on sort or page."

So I can click a sort button in the GridView from js, but thats less than Ideal.  I'd prefer to say

$("#list").gridview('reload') or $.fn.gridview.reload("#list") or some such sense.

Or do the way cool thing that is soo much simpler that you thought of just now.

Answer (score 47):

Execute `$.fn.yiiGridView.update("<id of CGridView>");`

Comment: Disadvantage of this command is that it resets filters, sorting and pagination. So if you order items by ID, go to 2nd page and than you call this command, current screen is lost and you have to find your item again.

Comment: $.fn.yiiListView.update("<id of CGridView>", {
        data: $("yourcustomselectors").serialize()
    });